# Default SecurityProtocol in PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am having a problem with a script running on a Windows 2016 Standard server with PowerShell 5.1, that is failing due to the default `SecurityProtocol` when making web requests using a `HttpClient`:

`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

I have spent a large amount of time researching this and I understand why it happens and the various options available to force a more secure protocol. However, I am completely stuck on why I am seeing different defaults between the problem server and my Windows 10 workstation, which are both running PowerShell 5.1.

**On the server (Windows 2016 Standard), where the script is failing:**

I see this for the default `SecurityProtocol`, specific weak protocols:

```
PS > [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
Ssl3, Tls
```

`$PsVersionTable` returns this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.3866
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.3866
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**On my workstation (Windows 10 2004), where the script works:**

A `SecurityProtocol` of `SystemDefault`:

```
PS > [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
SystemDefault
```

and for `$PsVersionTable`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.546
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.546
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

As you can see the two return different `SecurityProtocol` defaults but they only appear to differ by a minor PS version; `5.1.14393.3866` vs `5.1.19041.546`.

Both the server and workstation have a fairly vanilla set-up. None of the registry changes that are recommended to default to more secure protocols have been made to either box; i.e. `SchUseStrongCrypto`, properties under `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols`, etc. Both servers have up to and including .NET Framework 4.8 installed.

I really don't know where else to look as I'd be surprised if a difference in a minor PS version would bring about this change. Have I missed something (Windows security updates?)  or am I not understanding how the `SecurityProtocol` defaulting works?

Comment: On my Windows 10 (2004) I've got the same difference between PowerShell ISE and Powershell basic command line

Comment: Did you get it sorted? I've bumped into the same kind of issue. Updating the reg keys as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client didn't help :(

Comment: I was not able to find out why they were different, but what I ended up doing was putting the following in my scripts that ran.

Write-Log "SecurityProtocol was set to '$([Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol)' and has been changed to 'Tls12'."
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;